# How can I make programs reopen on startup on windows 8

Tags: windows-8

On macs there is a useful feature where if you log out of or shut down your mac, on login, all programs you had open previously, and the contents last open, display. I was wondering if there is a way to replicate this in windows 8. To clarify: I am not asking how to make a program run on startup, I am wanting that program to open with the same contents it had before being logged out.

As @DavidPostill pointed out:

> Please read the question carefully. OP wants to restore what he had before he shutdown or logged out.

Comment: use Hibernation

Answer (score 0):

Yes: Windows has two ways to do so.

- **Sleep** puts the processor into a low-power state, but does not completely shut down. This is useful for pausing work for a only few hours while on battery power, but stops and resumes the previous state in just a few seconds.
- **Hibernate** saves all work to disk. With a magnetic HDD, it may take 30 seconds or so to hibernate and to resume.

Comment: Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question. OP wants to restore what he had before he shutdown or logged out.

Comment: Not sure how that doesn't answer the question: both *Sleep* and *Hibernate* restore all applications to the state they were in before shutdown (though *Sleep* is not a true shutdown, admittedly). If a document is open in Writer or Word, or a web page in a browser, it is displayed just as it was before *Hibernate* was selected.

Comment: Sleep and Hibernate are **not the same** as Logoff or Shutdown which is what the OP is asking about.